# How does vector.push_back(object) copy an object and assign it to the newly appended element?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Let's say I have a struct:

```
struct obj
{
   int field1;
   int field2[10];
}
```

and vector:

```
vector<obj> objVector;
```

and I instantiate an object:

```
obj obj1;
```

when I call

```
vector.push_back(obj1)
```

How is obj1 stored into the vector? My professor told me that it is essentially duplicated; I was wondering how exactly that is done. Also, what if the obj1.field2 was initialized with predetermined values. How are all the elements in field2 duplicated into the vector?

Comment: Do you understand how `obj obj2 = obj1;` would duplicate `obj1`?

Comment: I do not. Can you explain or link me to a resource?

Comment: C++ uses value semantics. Assignment  (the `=` operator) always sets the value of the object on the left to be equal to the value of the object on the right. For example, in the case of `int`s, the `int` on the left of the `=` has its value set to be the same as the value of the `int` on the right. In `obj obj2 = obj1;` the `obj` on the left is set to have the same value as the `obj` on the right. For `class` types (which includes `struct`s) this is done using either `operator=` or a copy constructor which by default the compiler adds to all `class` types.

Comment: ... The compiler provided versions of these members simply apply the same operation to each member. So in your case, `obj`'s copy constructor will initialize the `field1` and `field2` members of the `obj` on the left to the same value as the respective members from the `obj` on the right. It is important to understand in C++ that each variables (except for references) are their own distinct object. Not to be confused by how things are done in other languages like Java and C# where variables are all references to an actual nameless object.

Answer (score 1):

> How is obj1 stored into the vector?

It is stored in an array.

> I was wondering how exactly that is done.

By copying.

The behaviour of the program may be undefined depending on context where `obj1` is declared. If it has automatic storage, then the values of the members are indeterminate, in which case the behaviour of copying the object is undefined.